# filter search is visible with some brands and need to be visible to all brands

Tags: magento-1.9, filter

We have a category brands, and with some brands the filter search is visible and with some brands it is not visible.
How can I change this so filter search is visible to  all brands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters appear of the categories have the flag `Is Anchor` set to `Yes`.
Check if this is the case for you. 
If so, mark all the subcategories you want to be filterable with `Is Anchor` `Yes`.

Comment: tnx Marius, and where can I find these settings? - found it!

Comment: you need to edit each category and look in the tabs of the category,